# IDEA not suggesting maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Mose of the time in my projects I can do a suggest on maven artifacts in IDEA, but sometimes it tells me "no suggestions", even though all dependencies and indices are up to date.

By sometimes I mean that this project worked prior having to reimport the project on an OS reinstall.

What should I check to discern why suggestions of artifacts, groups and versions is failing?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "sometimes it tells me that that won't work".

Comment: @vikingsteve not 100% certain by what you mean by "check your dependency actually includes that maven module via the pom.xml", I'm not having problems with modules actually working, but when editing pom.xml I can't get it to suggest the artifact names or versions, for example if I delete the 1 in `<version>3.0.1</version>` on `javax.servlet-api` and attempt to autocomplete available versions, I get "no suggestions". I have otherwise run through your suggestions, to no avail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. It's possible that IntelliJ only suggests artifacts that are indexed somehow, and that you need to re-index. Sorry if I cant help further.